# Changing symbolic link in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

Let me show my problem through screen shots.
[This is my first terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sjeU.png). I changed the link from another terminal say terminal2. My problem is highlighted in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBy9P.png) screen shots. Here the `ls` returns content of test1 folder after I changed the link into test2.

Comment: There's no issue. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: But I changed the link to test2, even after ls returns the files in test1. Is this behavior expected?

Comment: I don't see the command where you change the link to test2 (which would be something like `ln -sf test2 test`). `readlink` doesn't make links.

Comment: I know, it is done from another terminal. which is clearly mentioned above

Comment: Please understand my question once you answering or down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that is confusing you is that the `pwd` builtin doesn't actually tell you the current working directory -- it tells you the path that you used to get to the current working directory.

If you want the actual current working directory, you need the `-P` flag:

```
$ pwd -P
```

which will give you something like `/home/darkknight/test1`.

Comment: Thankyou, -P option of pwd was new information to me.

Answer (score 2):

That second call to `readlink` doesn't do what you think

```
darkknight@localhost:~/test$ readlink \`pwd`/home/darkknight/test2`
```

The description for `readlink` in the man page is

> Display value of a symbolic link on standard output

`readlink` is a read-only operation. You will also find the value of `$?` to be non-zero after this, meaning this has failed because `test2` is not a symlink.

Replace it with another call to `ln -s -f` (where -f stands for force) ...

```
darkknight@localhost:~$ ln -s -f test2 test
```

Not all distros honor `-f` so you may have to remove the symlink first:

```
darkknight@localhost:~$ rm test; ln -s test1 test
```

Comment: There was some formatting issue. please review the question once again.

Comment: Thank you, but I changed symbolic link after delete the previous one. but the issue still exist.

Comment: All evidence suggests you have not changed the symlink. At 1st blush your question still implies you believe `readlink` changes the symlink. There is no need to use more than one terminal.

I suggest you replace `readlink` with `ls -l ` which more clearly displays the situation.

Comment: I don't think `readlink` changes the symlink. It is used here to show the link is changed. And the issue happens  if changes symlink from another terminal (no matter whether it is needed or not).

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the expected behavior.

```
$ mkdir test1
$ mkdir test2
$ touch test1/t1
$ touch test2/t2
$ ln -s test1 test
$ cd test
$ ls
t1
$ rm ../test
$ ln -s test2 ../test
$ readlink ../test
test2
$ ls
t1
$
```

Simply imagine that when you `cd test` you actually enter `test1`. You can then change the symbolic link `test` to whatever you want -and even delete it!- you are still in `test1`.

```
$ pwd
test
$ readlink `pwd`
test2
$
```

For sure, `readlink` returns `test2`, as it goes and read the *current* `test` link that has been changed to `test2`. However, *at the time* you `cd` into `test`, the link *was* to `test1`. And you are still in the `test1` directory.

Of course, if now you change to the test directory, you'll be in `test2`.

```
$ cd ../test
$ ls
t2
$
```

One last thing, to clarify. Directory `test` *does not exist*. You cannot enter nor be in this directory. Whenever you `cd test`, you enter the directory the `test` symbolic link currently points to (here `test1`).

After you've entered the `test1` directory, you can change the `test` symbolic link to whatever you want, you'll still be in `test1`.

Comment: but `readlink` command returns new directory. it's shown in my question.

Answer (score 1):

*Now I changing the link to test2 from another terminal* : the command should be

```
rm -fr test;ln -s test2 test; cd test
```

Comment: No it ain't. you haven't issued `cd test` and therefore you are stuck in folder `test1` and have not traversed this stargate which now **would** lead you to folder `test2` as the `readlink` command correctly reports. 

 Please consider accepting my answer, it would help my rep tremendously.

Comment: This is not an answer that I required

Comment: Never mind accepting my answer: my reputation has surpassed the magical 15 and I am a happy puppy now. 

As per my answer: It is difficult to see after all your edits but your **original** question revealed a profound misconception of how symbolic links work: you expected the content of your current directory to change because you logged on in another terminal and changed the target of the symlink you used to enter said directory. My stargate metaphor was perfectly capable to clarify that for you if you cared to give it a thought.